# What's the syntax for returning a collection of collections?

Tags: vb.net, linq

The code below shows how I am attempting to return a collection of collections of objects.  Using the lambda-based LINQ syntax, I get what I want. Using the "natural language" syntax, I don't; I get a flat collection of objects. What's the phraseology to get a collection of collections?

```
Option Strict On

Sub Main

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim l As List(Of List(Of MyPoint)) = New List(Of List(Of MyPoint))
    For j = 1 To 2
        Dim ll = New List(Of MyPoint)
        For i = 1 To 10
            ll.Add(New MyPoint(i,j))
        Next
        l.Add(ll)
    Next

    Dim q1 = l.Select(Function (ll) ll.Select(Function (p) New MyPoint(p.x+1, p.y+1)))

    Dim q2 = From ll In l From p In ll Select New MyPoint(p.x + 1, p.y + 1)



End Sub

Public Class MyPoint
    Public Property X As Integer
    Public Property Y As Integer
    Sub New(i As Integer, j As Integer)
        X = i
        Y = j
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT: Using real class instead of anonymous type, and Option Strict On, so you can focus on the actual question instead of arguing with me.

Comment: What you have shown as "returns what i want" doesn't even compile (with Option Strict) because you declare a `List(Of List(Of Object))` but then you select `p.x` as if every object had a `x` property. That works only because of late binding. Why you still use `Option Strict Off`?

Comment: _"This does not return what I want"_ Ok, what does it return instead?

Comment: @TimSchmelter is correct, it's only working because of late binding, turn `Option Strict On`, he's your friend... Also why the `List(Of List(Of Object))` when you are clearly using `Integer` types, why not explicitly add the type you are using?

Comment: This throwaway code was thrown together in LinqPad specifically to pose this question. My actual code doesn't even use anonymous types. I think the question can be answered without focusing on `Option Strict`.

Comment: @Codexer I don't want a `List(Of List(Of Integer))`; I want a `List(Of List(Of *some other type*))`. In this throwaway code that's an anonymous type. In production, it happens to be `WebSupergoo.ABCPdf.XPoint`. If it would be clearer to you if I used that here, even though you could not compile it for yourself unless you own that library, then I can make that change.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "Ok, what does it return instead?" As I tried to state in the initial paragraph, I get a flat `List(Of *anonymous type*)` when what I want is a `List(Of List(Of *anonymous type*))`

Comment: `I think the question can be answered without focusing on Option Strict` indeed, **but** if it was on it would have told you about your problem.

Comment: @Codexer no, it would have told me that the code I was about to post to StackOverflow had a problem that SO users would ding me on. It has nothing to do with my production code, which *does* use `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Fine. I rewrote my **throwaway sample code** so you can focus on the question, if you decide to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `Select`s in the first one.  You need two `Select`s in the second one also;
(I renamed some things so it's easier to read)

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim listOfLists As List(Of List(Of Point)) = New List(Of List(Of Point))
For j = 1 To 2
    Dim ll = New List(Of Point)
    For i = 1 To 10
        ll.Add(New Point With {.x = i, .y = j})
    Next
    listOfLists.Add(ll)
Next

' This returns what I want    
Dim q1 = listOfLists.Select(Function(ll) ll.Select(Function(p) New With {.x = p.x + 1, .y = p.y + 1}))

Dim q2 = From thisList In listOfLists 
          Select From pnt In thisList 
                 Select New Point With {.x = pnt.x + 1, .y = pnt.y + 1}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed answer my question. So, asking the reverse question as a followup: what's the lambda-based syntax that is equivalent to just one Select? would it be SelectMany?